# Generating an HTML document given an XML file and XSLT, in a php context

Tags: php, xml, xslt

I have a challenge that I am not sure if I am following the right way in going about doing it. 
I have an XML file, that off course consists of data pertaining to a specific field. The idea is to dig into this XML file , retrieve the specific information in here and that I render as a drop down box. WHen something is selected from the drop down box, then information specific to the value chosen is rendered (of course the source of this information is the XML file).

My method:

I retrieve the XML information using simpleXMLelement functions, creating objects, subsequently decode and encode this in the a Mockclass.class.php file. For the page where I need to display the required information , I simply create an object of type class Mockclass and call upon the public methods to execute the desired operations. the data i render in pure html.

I am not sure if this is the right way to go about doing things, I want guidance on this if this is the right way to approach it or there are better alternatives and solutions etc?

Answer (score 2):

[`DOMDocument::load()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.load.php), [`XSLTProcessor`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.xsltprocessor.php), [`DOMDocument::saveHTMLFile()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtmlfile.php).